# uilabel with autolayouts resize with padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout

I have uilabel with a uitableviewcell. It resizes with autolayouts but it doesnt keep the padding. How can add padding and keep the padding after autolayout resizes the uilabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this guide on how to add constraints in the IB.
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Basically, what you need is just to add a constraint that will determine the padding of the label.

Good Luck!